# VHDL: Is it possible to concurrently shift array elements?

Tags: arrays, vhdl, insertion-sort

I would like to crearte own implementation of insertion sort for learning purposes.
As you may now, one of the steps reqiure shifting array elements to right by 1. The main difficulty here that the range of this operation has to be dynamic.

so if sort_reg is array from 0 to array_length, I need to acheive sort_reg(n)<=sort_reg(n-1), sort_reg(n-1)<=sort_reg(n-2) ... sort_reg(n-i+1)<=sort_reg(n-i); (n-m)>=i>=1, where m starting array index of the range,  which would be shifted right by 1  from range ( m to n-1) to (m+1 to n).

The question is if it is possible to acheive this in one step, and then how?

Comment: Please clarify which range must be dynamic, `n` or `m` or both?

Comment: yes I was probably not clear enough, that both need to be dynamic. m is the destination index of the member that is moved. That is how insertion sort works: find a the first member *n* that is less than current position m and _insert_ it at *m* (n>m). for that porpuse range from *m* to *n-1* has to be moved to *m+1* to *n*.
also forgot to mention that is has to be synthesizable under Xilinx Vivado for Zynq device

Comment: Got it. I have extended my example. It synthesizes with Quartus-II but I can't check if it works with Vivado yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is possible in one step. You must store the element in registers and than assign the new value for all array elements at the same rising edge.

Let's make a simple example with just two signals a and b of type `std_logic`. Then this process would swap both elements at the rising edge of the `clock`:

```
process(clock)
begin
  if rising_edge(clock) then
    a <= b;
    b <= a;
  end if;
end process;
```

This works, because the signals get there new values after the process has finished. Thus, in the assignment of `b` the old value of `a` (before the rising clock edge) is assigned.

Let's continue with your example.
You didn't specify an specific array, so I take this one:

```
type array_type is array(0 to SIZE-1) of std_logic_vector(7 downto 0);
signal sort_reg : array_type;
```

Then the process can be written using a for loop.
**EDIT**: Within each iteration step, an`if` statement can be used to check if an element should be actually shifted. The signals `n` and `m` should be of type `unsigned` (prefered), or `integer` with range 0 to SIZE-1. 
**EDIT 2**: Example changed to rotation as indicated in comments.

```
-- value to insert in case of rotation
value_to_insert <= sort_reg(to_integer(n)); -- to_integer required if type of 'n' is unsigned

process(clock)
begin
  if rising_edge(clock) then
    -- This loop is unrolled by the synthesis tool.
    for i in SIZE-1 downto 1 loop
      -- shift elements [n-1:m] to [n:m+1]
      if (i <= n) and (i >= m+1) then
        sort_reg(i) <= sort_reg(i-1);
      end if;

      -- insert new value
      if i = m then
        sort_reg(i) <= value_to_insert;
      end if;
    end loop;

    -- insert into position zero
    if m = 0 then
      sort_reg(0) <= value_to_insert;
    end if;
  end if;
end process;
```

Comment: shouldnt it be `if (i<=n) and (i>=m+1)` ?

Comment: I realize now, that I probably could simplify the task description by explaining that i would like to rotate a dynamic range of an array. (of which shifting is a suboperation)  
I implemented a module for testing that  takes an array of integers, m ,n as inputs and rotates range m to n using method suggested by you. I simulated it Vivado and it looks alright
Thank you!

Comment: @AndreyPro You are right, but this `if` condition only applies to the range specified in the comments. I have taken this for now. But, your original question still uses another shift range, i.e., shift elements n-1 downto n-m one position up. Please edit your question to avoid confusion.

Comment: oh I see. I used m in 2 different senses and confused everybody :-/. Sorry for that. I will clarify

Answer (score 0):

How about this;

```
sort_reg <= sort_reg(1 to sort_reg'high) & sort_reg(0);
```

I'm assuming `sort_reg` is a signal defined as;

```
signal sort_reg : some_array_type(0 to N);
```

In this case `sort_reg'high` is an attribute that is equal to `N`.

In vhdl `&` is used as concatenation operators. It joins two vector/arrays together to form a single vector/array.

Above example shifts only by 1 item. If you want to shift by `M`, you can use something like this;

```
sort_reg <= sort_reg(M to sort_reg'high) & sort_reg(0 to M-1);
```

Note that if you want to shift a signal (not assign it to a different signal) you should do it in a process as described by [Martin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33947501/432492).

Comment: I am alright with shift by 1.
I am going to use it inside an FSM so probabbly I will assign it like sort_reg_next(i-1)<=sort_reg(i)